# Как компилировать код на C в macOS?

Tags: c, macos, компиляция, компилятор

Каким образом можно работать с языком `C` в macOS? Нужен именно `C`, не `C++`.

Я совсем новичок в этом. Пробовал поставить VS Code с расширениями позволяющими якобы компилировать код на `C`. К сожалению, ничего не вышло.

Чем я могу воспользоваться для компиляции `C`? Возможно какая-то IDE или же можно как-то использовать VS Code/Sublime Text? Будут интересны различные варианты/инструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Как варик, через терминал:

```
gcc -o hello main.c
./hello
```

Если это крупный проект - то через Xcode:

> Xcode supports source code for the programming languages C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, AppleScript, Python, Ruby, ResEdit (Rez), and Swift, with a variety of programming models

Если ты студент или не проч платить за IDE - CLion в помощь)